# Extract data from HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I want get data from html table from an another html page. I [read](http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/) extract data from table with jQuery, but it was in same html file.

I will extract data from another html file, how I can do it?
I must get data from [here](http://linux2.jumboserver.com:9450/played.html?sid=1).

Comment: Use jQuery ajax and load the content either using `.load()` or `$.ajax` or `$.get/$.post`

Comment: And once you load the content you can process it as you would a simple string.

Comment: Hey @MuraliMurugesan, I found a better way for it. I found a new url [here](http://linux2.jumboserver.com:9450/currentsong). So, I must get text from this html basicly.